# When is the getCount and getView called in list adapter?

Tags: android, listview

my app works fine but I am trying to understand how the ListAdapter works, more specifically when and how the getCount and getView methods are called.

I understood that:

- getView is called when items are created in the list;
- getCount is called to get back the number of items;

I debugged my app to see when and how these methods are called.
This is what I found:

- when i have 0 items in the list

  - getView is not called --> i'm ok with that, there are no items to show
  - getCount is called 6 times
- when i have 1 item in the list

  - getView is called 9 times (with position 0)
  - getCount get called 23 times (with result 1)
- when i have 2 items in the list

  - getView is called 9 times (with positions 0 and 1)
  - getCount get called 11 times (with result 2)

**content_history_list.xml**

```
    <ListView
       android:id="@+id/listView"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:dividerHeight="2dp" />
```

**activity.java**

```
class ListViewItem {

    public String cost, date, category;

}

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_history_list);
    List<ListViewItem> listViewItems = new ArrayList<ListViewItem>();

    // here i fill up my list with items

    ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listview.setAdapter(new CustomAdapterHistoryList(this, listViewItems));
```

**customlistitem.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/customlistiem_Category"
    android:layout_width="100sp"
    android:layout_height="36sp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:text="Category" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/customlistiem_Cost"
    android:layout_width="60sp"
    android:layout_height="36sp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:background="@color/customlistitem_Cost"
    android:text="Cost" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/customlistiem_Description"
    android:layout_width="130sp"
    android:layout_height="36sp"

    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:text="Description" 
    android:gravity="center_vertical"/>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/customlistiem_Date"
    android:layout_width="80sp"

    android:layout_height="36sp"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@color/customlistitem_Date"
    android:text="Date" />
```

**CustomAdapterHistoryList.java**

```
public class Holder {
    TextView tvCost, tvCategory, tvDate;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Calling getView...Position: " + position);
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Holder holder = new Holder();
    View rowView;

    rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customlistitem, null);

    ListViewItem item = result.get(position);

    holder.tvCost = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.customlistiem_Cost);
    holder.tvCategory = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.customlistiem_Category);
    holder.tvDate = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.customlistiem_Date);

    holder.tvCost.setText(item.cost);
    holder.tvCategory.setText(item.category);
    holder.tvDate.setText(item.date);

    rowView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(context, "You Clicked " + result.get(position).category.toString() + " " + result.get(position).cost.toString() + " " + result.get(position).date.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    return rowView;
}
```

Looking forward to hear your feedbacks! Thanks!!!!

Comment: `getView` should only be called once per item. Are you modifying the list in some place, calling datasetchanged? You should also inclode when and how you change and interact with the adapter

Comment: i have added the source...i basically call the setAdapter only once (onCreate) and that's it, there are no iterations involved